# How to get element id from xml url string

Tags: c#, .net

I need to import some xml data into my application but i cant find out how to get the element attribute from the product element.

i havent really tried anything because i dont know how to troubleshoot this problem.

this is the xml file i have :

```
<Products>
<Product Id="2108">
<EAN>7081014655182</EAN>
<Title>MaCo Roodschillige aardappelen</Title>
<Brand>MaCoFood</Brand>
<Shortdescription>Veelzijdige rode aardappel</Shortdescription>
<Fulldescription/>
<Image>https://www.mupload.nl/img/bg193vurxpk.jpg</Image>
<Weight>1 kg</Weight>
<Price>0.00</Price>
<Category>Aardappel, groente, fruit</Category>
<Subcategory>Aardappelen</Subcategory>
<Subsubcategory>Aardappel - ongeschild</Subsubcategory>
</Product>
</Products>
```

This is how i get the rest of the attributes

```
 string xmlurl = "https://supermaco.starwave.nl/api/products";

            var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlurl);



            List<Products> itemlist = doc.Root
                .Descendants("Product")
                .Select(node => new Products
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(node.Element("Id").Value),
                    EAN = node.Element("EAN").Value,
                    Brand = node.Element("Brand").Value,
                    Shortdescription = node.Element("Shortdescription").Value,
                    Fulldescription = node.Element("Fulldescription").Value,
                    Image = node.Element("Image").Value,
                    Weight = node.Element("Weight").Value,
                    Price = double.Parse(node.Element("Price").Value),
                    Category = node.Element("Category").Value,
                    Subcategory = node.Element("Subcategory").Value,
                    Subsubcategory = node.Element("Subsubcategory").Value
                })
                .ToList();

            foreach (var item in itemlist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EAN : " + item.EAN );
            }

            return Ok();
```

Please note that "Id = int.Parse(node.Element("Id").Value)" does not work.

I hope someone can tell me how i get the id element from the Product element. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Id is not an `element`, it is called an XML `Attribute`.

Just use `node.Attribute("Id").Value`.

Still, I would advise in trying to use an `XmlSerializer`, in order to manage the mapping of the fields. Search for it and you'll find plenty of tutorials. You can then decorate the `Product` class with attributes mapping both elements and attributes.